# Is there a way to obtain names of method parameters in Java?

Tags: java, reflection

I'm writing small and very [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DRY) framework, which heavily relies on metadata. I'd like to know if there is a way to obtain method parameter names, i.e. given some method

```
public void a(int myIntParam, String theString) { ... }
```

get the strings `"myIntParam"` and `"theString"`.

I know I could annotate parameters, but that wouldn't be nice...

```
public void a(
    @Param("myIntParam") int myIntParam,
    @Param("theString") String theString
) { ... }
```

Comment: Not really, but codehaus have this library that will do for a lot of purposes: http://paranamer.codehaus.org/

Comment: Blimey, I had no idea about this thing... I guess you learn something every day!

Comment: Very interesting thing.. But I don't want to introduce any dependences, and the way it operates is rather complicated.

Comment: Are you working with source files or classes?

Comment: It is possible with Java 8, take a look at [my answer to a related question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20594685/607767).

Comment: I answered the same question here: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237803/can-i-obtain-method-parameter-name-using-java-reflection/41463408#41463408>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We created a custom annotation for the method that holds a String[] of parameter names.  This approach felt a little easier to manage than having to annotate each individual parameter.  We plan to add build-time checking that the number of annotated parameter names matches the number of arguments, since that it what we require.

Comment: Very good idea! I'll definitely convert all those @Param to single @Params.

Comment: Actually I prefer to annotate them individually, because this makes the annotation optional. I use these annotations to create a webpage to call methods using reflection. If I forget to annotate a parameter then the code just falls back and visualizes it as "paramX" to the end-user. On the other hand if you put all names inside one annotation, then there's no decent fallback.

Answer (score 16):

Here is a dirty solution that needs some tweaking. Maybe someone can make it better.

#### Cons:

- Requires that you know the location of compiled class file.
- It has to be compiled with the -g flag.

#### Code:

```
import com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.classfile.ClassParser;
import com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.classfile.JavaClass;
import com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.classfile.LocalVariable;
import com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.classfile.Method;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      ClassParser parser = new ClassParser("Main.class");
      JavaClass clazz = parser.parse();

      for (Method m : clazz.getMethods()) {
          System.out.println("Method: " + m.getName());
          int size = m.getArgumentTypes().length;
          if (!m.isStatic()) {
            size++;
          }

          for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
              LocalVariable variable = m.getLocalVariableTable().getLocalVariable(i);
              System.out.println("  - Param: " + variable.getName());
          }
      }
  }

  public void a(int myIntParam, String theString) {
  }
}
```

#### Output:

`$ javac -g Main.java`
`$ java Main`
`Method: <init>`
`- Param: this`
`Method: main

  - Param: args

Method: a

  - Param: this

  - Param: myIntParam

  - Param: theString`

Answer (score 9):

I could be wrong about this... but I don't think parameter names appear in a class file so I would guess that there is no way to get them via reflection.

Answer (score 3):

The name of the parameters are present in the class file, when the java code was compiled with debugging information (via the -g option). The class file then contains a LocalVariableTable attribute (see http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html#5956). This contains the names of local variables and parameters are just local variables. The parameters correspond to the variable slots starting at index 1 (or index 0 for static methods).

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Spring you are in luck. Just add this to your applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer"/>
```

Then you can inject this bean where it is needed:

```
@Autowired
private ParameterNameDiscoverer parameterNameDiscoverer;

Method m = ...
String[] names = parameterNameDiscoverer.getParameterNames(m);
```

As its name suggests, this implementation relies on classes being compiled with debug info.

Answer (score 2):

@bobwienholt is correct - parameter names are not compiled into java classes, and so aren't available at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Parameter names are available through [apt](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/jdk/api/apt/mirror/overview-summary.html) (now part of javac).

Comment: @Tom: do you still need to explicitly annotate classes to get apt to preprocess them? Or is a more general-purpose precompiler now?

Comment: I believe annotation processors can ask to receive all classes whether they have annotations or not. It's not really a preprocessor as the original classes are left alone, although other classes and artifacts can be created.