# Get the parameter names of an interface method

Tags: java, spring

I need to get the parameter names of a method at runtime. Is there any way to achieve this?

I tried using `LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer` which is a Spring class. But it works only for classes and not the interfaces.

Comment: The only way this is really possible is through parsing a `.java` file.

Comment: Here is something similar, might be all you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237803/can-i-obtain-method-parameter-name-using-java-reflection

Comment: As far as I know it will be possible in Java 8 reflection, otherwise you shall use bytcode manipulating libraries.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate, his question is about getting the parameter names from a method defined in an interface and not a class.

Comment: The answer is: its not possible even when compiled with debug symbols, the parameter names are not in the byte code. http://www.jroller.com/eu/entry/using_asm_to_read_mathod

Comment: Are you sure you need the parameter names?

Comment: This question is definitely not duplicate. Still can't find a way to get parameter names from interfaces. Any help ?

Comment: The Java8 solution described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20594685/466738) makes it a duplicate. Notice the need of compiling with `-parameters` flag.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to obtain the parameter names is to compile the source code using `-g:vars` options. This generates a `LocalVariableTable` attribute into the class file. This is generally removed for optimization.

For example: ([taken from here](http://arhipov.blogspot.in/2011/01/java-bytecode-fundamentals.html))

```
public class Example {
   public int plus(int a){
     int b = 1;
     return a + b;
   }
 }
```

This will create a `LocalVariableTable` as follows

LocalVariableTable:

```
   Start  Length  Slot  Name     Signature
   0      6       0     this     LExample;
   0      6       1     a        I
   2      4       2     b        I
```

The `LocalVariableTable` can be read using any byte code instrumentation libraries like [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/doc/tutorial-asm-2.0.html) or [Javassist](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/).

Comment: Will this work for java Interfaces too?

Comment: I have not tried myself but when compiled, interface translates to a .class file eventually, that why it should be consistent with .class of a Java Class file.