# Java / Get all arguments in reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I search way to get all the names of a function in java. for example:

```
public String doSomething(String user, boolean tree, String[] arr){
// HERE I want to get all the names of the params, meaning: user, tree and arr, and do something with them
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237803/can-i-obtain-method-parameter-name-using-java-reflection

Answer (score 0):

You can, but only if you have debugging information in the code.  The names of these variables exist mainly for you, not for the processor.

Details here:

[Can I obtain method parameter name using Java reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237803/can-i-obtain-method-parameter-name-using-java-reflection)