# Java Reflection- getting names of parameter types

Tags: java, reflection

```
for(Method m: c.getMethods()){
 Type[] parameters = m.getParameterTypes();
String[] theParameters;
        for (Type par: parameters){
            theParameters.add(par.getSimpleName());
        }
```

I am trying to store the names of each of the parameters in a String array but this doesnt seem to work

Comment: Java `arrays` do not have an `add` method. Did you mean to use `ArrayList` instead?

Comment: yes sorry, i tried it using na ArrayList aswell.

Comment: List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();

Comment: Yes, this will take care of one of the problems.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to get actual parameter "names" and not their types, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237803/can-i-obtain-method-parameter-name-using-java-reflection)