# Preserving parameter names in java interfaces

Tags: java, reflection

Is there a way to fetch parameter names of Interfaces from compiled source at runtime?

Use case: I am creating some proxy instances based on some interfaces. I need to get parameter names to create some SQL statements.

Any help?

Comment: Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237803/can-i-obtain-method-parameter-name-using-java-reflection

Comment: @PeterMmm could you point which part I need to read? I had already read but I might be missing something. The question is related to class.

Comment: In this case it is the same for class + interface methods. Cleanest thing is to use annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Java SE 8, this is possible if you compiled your interfaces with the -parameters option:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodparameterreflection.html