# Print parameters passed into methods Generic Way

Tags: java

Is it possible to write a method or a way to print parameters of any method?
I mean assume that I have two methods like

```
calculate(int a,int b) {}

notifyResult(int type){}
```

so I want a method that print `"a"` and `"b"` upon calculate method invocation
same things will happen upon invoing notifyResult print `"type".`

I know that using reflection or AOP tech can help me?
Is there an other way to do that?

Comment: Do you want to print the _values_ of `a` and `b` or the parameter names themselves?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Java 8 you can [obtain the name of method argument](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodparameterreflection.html).

To do that you will have to compile your code with option `-parameters`.

Then form instance of [Executable] class (Method or Constructor) you can use method `getParameters()` to obtain array of [Parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Parameter.html) instances. The method getName() will resolve you the names.

```
private void example(Class<?> type) {

 for(Method method : type.getMethods()){
   for(Parameter parameter : getParameters()) {
       System.out.println("%s",parameger.getName());
   }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct method to do this. I mean, there is no java API that can retrieve you parameters.

You can however use the the following approaches.

1. Add log message in the beginning of each method. Print all arguments manually.
2. Use byte code engineering
3. Use (dynamic) proxy

Examples of byte code engineering libraries are [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/), [CGLIB](https://github.com/cglib/cglib), [Javassist](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/). Example of higher level, AOP library is [AspectJ](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/).

Answer (score 0):

you can do that in **Java 8**:

```
Class<String> someClass = String.class;
for (Method someMethod : someClass.getDeclaredMethods()) {
   for (Parameter p : someMethod.getParameters()) {
      System.err.println("  " + p.getName());
   }
}
```

And to have and over view look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237803/can-i-obtain-method-parameter-name-using-java-reflection)