# Getting passed parameter name in java?

Tags: java, method-parameters

How do I get a passed parameter name i.e the name with which it was passed at runtime?

For example:

```
int mParam = 10;

public void func (int myParam){
 //print wanted name
}

func(mParam);
```

Wanted output:

```
mParam
```

Using reflection, I managed to get:

```
myParam
```

Comment: Scroll down in the duplicate question for the Java 8 solution.

Comment: @rgettman I don't think the OP wants a parameter name, I think they want a *field* name (that happens to get passed as a parameter). It's not entirely clear. Notice that the specified output is *not* a parameter name in their example.

Comment: @PaulBoddington Yes, it wasn't clear.  But because the desired output is "mParam", not "myParam", I'll un-dup it.  (Already un-duped.)

Comment: @PaulBoddington If that's the case, I'm not sure that's possible. Even if it were, that sounds like a a very poor, hacky solution to an XY problem.

Comment: @PaulBoddington I'm not sure I understood you. If I call func(foo) it should print "foo", if we call func(bar) it should print "bar"

Comment: Why  do you need the name? Incase you need it for changing its value or anything, pass by reference will do good to you. Let us know why you want it so we can help you with a better solution to the actual requirement

Comment: Wouldn't `mParam` be evaluated as `10`, then `func(10)` is called? If so, how would you get the name? The method shouldn't know what variable was passed to it, only the value given

Comment: @osh Integers do not have names.  If an integer happens to be stored in a particular variable, that fact is not conveyed by the integer itself.

Comment: @osh What should `func(foo + bar)` print? The method doesn't make sense.

Comment: this is not a variable `mParam` that is passed to `func()`, only its value. Inside `func()` it is impossible to discover which particular variable it initially belonged to.

Comment: You cannot do this in Java.

Comment: Which output would you expect on `func(42);`? Wanted to say you are asking for an information, that isn't there. Calls on methods transport parameters, no parameter meta information.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I understand my mistake now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think It is not possible in java. Since java uses pass by value to pass the parameter. So when you pass the parameter to func() it only passes the value of variable nothing else.

It is possible to know about the parameter defined by function using reflect.parameter package in java.If you want to know the parameter details of the function you calling you can check out this question
[Can I obtain method parameter name using Java reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237803/can-i-obtain-method-parameter-name-using-java-reflection?lq=1)

But you can not know the name of the parameter which is passed.

Answer (score -1):

You can change your method func to receive 2 params such as:

```
public void func (int myParam, String myParamName){
 //print wanted name
}
```

Or better yet to pass a Map as a parameter:

```
    public void func (Map<String, Integer> map){
 //print wanted name
}
```

This way you can pass named integers and get your integer by name in your method