# How to pass -parameters javac flag to Java compiler via Gradle?

Tags: gradle, javac

I have a Gradle-managed multi-project setup that relies on the new Java 8 `-parameters` compiler flag. I need 2 ways of including the compiler flag:

- To test classes only (the main project should compile without parameter names attached).
- To all compiled sources.

I've tried this:

```
  tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs << '-parameters'
    options.fork = true
    options.forkOptions.executable = 'javac'
  }
```

...but it does not seem to be working properly.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You should use standard way of configuring Java compile plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

compileJava {
    options.compilerArgs << '-parameters'
}
```

Comment: The code snippet works (of course), but the comment supplied is somewhat... So, the "standard" is actually the totally opposite to what Gradle guys recommend.
The requester is using  much closer to using configuration avoidance, and configuring task for all `sourceSets`, etc. (`compileJava` affect only `main` sourceSet).
The "accepted" answer is nothing of that, the answer below is much much much better. @JustACluelessNewbie reconsider. ) Gradle experts make some up/down votes. Sorry for criticising comment. )

Comment: But the answers below don't seem relevant to the question of how to pass `-parameters` they're referencing Spring, Dagger or a release version instead?

Answer (score 13):

For Android projects, one can add e.g. the below in the gradle android scope.

```
// Used to get more info from dagger regarding binding compile errors
// see https://github.com/google/dagger/wiki/Dagger-2.17-@Binds-bugs
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs += ["-Adagger.floatingBindsMethods=enabled"]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to add support for parameters in a kotlin project.
The way to do it was to set the [javaParameters](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle-compiler-options.html#attributes-specific-to-jvm) kotlin option

```
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_11.toString()

    javaParameters = true
}
```

Comment: Close, but not exactly. Full configuration in gradle kotlin is `tasks.compileKotlin { kotlinOptions { javaParameters = true } }`

Comment: @MiguelGamboa you're right, your snippet works for all compile tasks. My snippet was specific to an android project

Answer (score 1):

Answer from @Crazyjavahacking is correct

Also, check that you doesn't redifine it, like me, in a subproject that uses others args (mapstruct in my case) :

`options.compilerArgs = ['-Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring'] // do not do this`

Always append the args `options.compilerArgs << '-Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring'`

Hope it can save some time to someone else, i personnaly lost 2 hours since i totally forgot this line in the subproject and was concentrating on the main build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

When using a Kotlin config file for a Java project, with a `build.gradle.kts` file, the above suggestions did not work. This did:

```
tasks.withType<JavaCompile> {
  // Support Beam's @JavaBeanSchema with @SchemaCreate all-args constructors
  options.compilerArgs.add("-parameters")
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
compileJava {
  options.compilerArgs.addAll(['--release', javaVersion])
}
```