# Is it possible to get the parameter names of a method in scala

Tags: scala, parameters

As far as I know, we can't do this in Java. Can we do this in scala?

Suppose there is a method as following:

```
def insert(name:String, age:Int) {
    // insert new user
}
```

Is it possible to get the parameter names `name` and `age` in scala?

---

UPDATE

I want to do this, because I want to bind the parameters of methods automaticlly.

For example, this is a web app, it has some actions defined as:

```
class UsersController extends Controller {
    def create(name: String, age: Int) {
          // insert the user
    }
}
```

A client clicked the `submit` button of a creating-user form. The url will be `/users/create` and with some parameters sending.

On the server side, when we get a url named `/users/create`, we will find a method `create` in the controller `UsersController`, found one now. Then I have to get the parameter names of that method, then we can get the values of them:

```
val params = getParamsFromRequest()
val method = findMethodFromUrl("/users/create")
val paramNames = getParamNamesOfMethod(method)
val paramValues = getValues(params, paramNames)

// then invoke
method.invoke(controller, paramValues)
```

Now, the key is how to get the parameter names of a method?

Comment: What do you want do do? Get the names of the method?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's still **very much** a [work in progress](https://github.com/scalaj/scalaj-reflect), but you should be able to:

```
import scalaj.reflect._
for {
  clazz <- Mirror.ofClass[UsersController].toSeq
  method <- clazz.allDefs.find(_.name == "insert").toSeq
  params <- method.flatParams
} yield params
```

Sorry about the `toSeqs`, they're to work around a known issue using `Option`s in a for-comprehension.

Please don't push it *too* hard, it's still very young and fragile. I'm certainly not at the stage yet where I'd accept bug reports :)

**UPDATE**

Well... I know that I said I'm not accepting bug reports, but this one seemed so useful that I've pushed it up to github anyway.

To do the job dynamically (from a String class name):

```
import scalaj.reflect._
for {
  clazz <- Option(Class forName "x.y.UsersController")
  mirror <- Mirror.ofClass(clazz).toSeq
  method <- mirror.allDefs.find(_.name == "insert").toSeq
  params <- method.flatParams
} yield params
```

Comment: @Freewind - Okay, I've updated my answer (and the project) with a solution to the problem of building mirrors from a class name string.

Answer (score 2):

This question has some insight on how it is done in Java: [Is there a way to obtain names of method parameters in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381502/is-there-a-way-to-obtain-names-of-method-parameters-in-java)

Comment: thank you very much, that's very helpful. I still have a question, why not scala add this feature? I don't think it's a problem.

Comment: If there is no such feature in scala, then that is probably because java doesn't have one directly yet; and that could mean future trouble.  Here is a discussion about parameter names in Java 6 for more insight (I don't know where the feature stands in Java 7): http://paulhammant.com/blog/parameter-names-for-java6-answer.html

I believe scala do use the parameter names in compile time for named parameters. That'll have to come from the debug information of the class.

Comment: Actually, it comes from the "scala signature", which is encoded as a sequence of bytes in an annotation named `ScalaSig` attached to every class file that scalac emits.

Comment: Ah, I stand corrected. Sounds like a much more trustworthy solution as well.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just using different method names (to reflect the parameters that may be passed)? Like, `craeteWithNameAndAgeAndGender` (pretty standard approach). You won't anyways be able to have multiple methods with the same names(/arity/parameter types and order) and just different parameter names - method overloading doesn't work this way.

Comment: maybe I haven't express clearly. I used `reflection` to get the method names, and if I want to auto-binding, I have to get the method names. But I can't get them by java relection.